# Making eshell expand .. like bash

Tags: emacs, eshell

In bash, due to the layout of my keyboard, I often do `cd ..<tab>` to have it expand the trailing slash, however, eshell does not do this out of the box. How would I go about making it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is controlled by the variable `eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore`.  Try

```
(setq eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore "\\`\\(CVS\\)/\\'")
```